# Download Table to excel With hidden rows with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, export-to-excel, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table created using ng-repeat. In this table i have the used ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end in order to hide some row which will be visible only when the user wants to see it. Now my problem is that when i try to export this table to Excel the rows which are visible only appear in the excel also as there are rows which are linked each other appear as different rows(as in the table also they are different rows). Now what i want is that all the rows whether visible or not should appear in the excel. An is there a way that two rows which are linked to each other(as they contain data related to one single instance) can appear as single row in excel. Here is my code

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.exportData = function () {
        var table = document.getElementById('exportable');
        var html = table.outerHTML;
        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
   };

    $scope.items = [{
        "Name": "Name1",
            "Date": "10/02/2014",
            "Terms": ["samsung", "nokia", "apple"]
    }, {
        "Name": "Name2",
            "Date": "10/02/2014",
            "Terms": ["motrolla", "nokia", "iPhone"]
    }]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="exportData()" >Export</button>
    <br />
    <table width="100%" id='exportable'>
            <thead>
                <tr >
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Terms</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat-start="item in items">
                    <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Date}}</td>
                    <td><span ng-repeat="term in item.Terms">{{term}}{{!$last?', ':''}}</span></td>
                    <td>
                      <button ng-click="item.expanded=true">
                      more
                      </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="item.expanded">
                  <td colspan=''>
                    
                  </td>
                  <td colspan=''>
                    Hello
                  </td>
                  <td >
                    <button ng-click="item.expanded=false">
                      Hide
                      </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    
</div>
  </body>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cb73kjvv/2/)
Any Help would be appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-show` insted of `ng-if` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cb73kjvv/3/)

```
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="item.expanded">
```

Comment: ya i did that and now all rows will come but rows which are linked should come in one single row do you have any idea about that.